# Are the two triangles similar?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A book I was answering was asking for the center of enlargement and the scale factor of the two similar figures.But I don't think the two triangles are similar. They corresponding sides don't have the same ratios. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: Yes:  Black:  base=height=2;  Red:  base=height=4.

Comment: It's a bit tricky because A, B, C don't correspond to A', B', and C' respectively. But the triangles are similar. ABC ~ C'A'B'.

Comment: Does that mean BA and B'A' are not corresponding sides?

Comment: It's not true that "$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle A'B'C'$" according to the way the triangles are named. However, it is true that "*this* triangle is similar to *that* one". (As David notes, we have isosceles triangles whose base-to-height ratios match.) Without seeing the wording of the problem at hand, it's impossible to say what may be going on here; perhaps the figure is simply mislabeled, or perhaps the author is providing an object lesson about how corresponding elements aren't *required* to have matchy labels (although matchy labels are certainly helpful).

Comment: Oh. I learned from geometry that similar triangles must be labeled correctly, especially when they are transformed like in transformation lessons

Comment: @harpey1111: Certainly, if one reads "$\triangle ABC\sim\triangle XYZ$", then one expects $A$, $B$, $C$ to correspond to $X$, $Y$, $Z$ in order. If the book has written "$\triangle ABC\sim\triangle A'B'C'$" alongside the figure, then it's technically incorrect. However, if the book simply indicated "the triangles are similar", then you shouldn't get too caught-up in the labels. What *I* call *my* triangle and what *you* call *your* triangle may not be label-compatible, yet the triangles can be similar. (And, again, it's also possible that the figure is simply mislabeled. Errors happen.)

Comment: the lesson is transformation (dilation), so it requires all the vertices of the image to be labeled correctly. If the triangles are similar, then it's really a dilation. I think the vertices of the image are mislabeled or there's something on the dilation I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes

In isosceles $\Delta ABC$ , $BC=2, AB=AC=\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt5$

In isosceles $\Delta C'B'A'$ , $A'B'=4, A'C'=B'C'=\sqrt{2^2+4^2}=2\sqrt5$
$$\frac{AB}{C'B'}=\frac{AC}{C'A'}=\frac{\sqrt5}{2\sqrt5}=\frac12, \ \ \frac{BC}{B'A'}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac12$$
$$\frac{AB}{C'B'}=\frac{BC}{B'A'}=\frac{AC}{C'A'}=\frac12$$
$$\therefore \Delta ABC\sim\Delta C'B'A'$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. Consider pairwise parallels:

$$ ( AB// A'C'),( AC// B'C'), (BC// B'A') $$

By a simple construction alternate angles an be seen equal. The corresponding included acute angles are equal. So the triangles are similar.

The same is true for the second possibility as well.